# Javascript for removing options from dropdown list

Tags: javascript

I have dropdownlist with following html code that I grabbed from debug window. It is a code in blackbox that I can't get to. In this webpage I want to use javascript to remove the options if it does not start with 'SS '. How do I do that?

```
<select id="prgid" special="lists.specprog" name="UF-003054-1">
<option value=""> </option>
<option value="5488">SS Twain CE</option>
<option value="5487">Twain IS</option>
</Select>
```

I am doing something like this which is not working. Please help.

```
var select=document.getElementById('prgid');
            for (i=0;i<select.length;  i++) {
                var prg = select.options[i].value;
                if (!prg.substring,0,3) == 'SS ') { 
                 select.remove(i);
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea. Try this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('prgid');
for (var i in select.children) {
    if (select.children[i].innerHTML.match('SS') !== 0) {
        select.children[i].outerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/35vagg9u/

Answer (score 0):

You're close, you just missed a couple things

```
var prg = select.options[i].value;
//should be
var prg = select.options[i].text;
```

Should use .text, because .value will return 5488 and 5487, .text will return "SS Twain CE" And "Twain IS"

And your substring method wasn't formatted correctly, it should have been

```
if (prg.substring(0, 3) != 'SS ')
```

Putting it all together

```
var select=document.getElementById('prgid');
for (i=0;i<select.length;  i++) {
    var prg = select.options[i].text;
    if (prg.substring(0, 3) != 'SS ') { 
       select.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var select=document.getElementById('prgid');
for (i=0;i<select.length;  i++) {
    var prg = select.options[i].text;
    if (prg.substring(0,3) == 'SS ') { 
        select.remove(i);
    }        
}
```

Use the above javascript.
you have to use `select.options[i].text` to get option text. But if you use `.value` that will give you the option value. And see the syntax of .substring()

For code reference, see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0q2rs5s/2/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. it was a great help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, howderek already posted a good working alternative, but it may be worth posting a fixed version of your code for a better understanding of what went wrong. You were pretty close!

There were just a couple of missteps:

The condition within the if statement:

```
!prg.substring,0,3) == 'SS '
```

should instead have been:

```
prg.substring(0,3) != 'SS '
```

You were calling the `substring()` function incorrectly, and furthermore your placement of the `!` operator would have caused you to compare a casted boolean against a string, rather than a string against a string (which is what you would want in this case).

Additionally, since you're actually accessing the text of the options, and not their values, you should use `select.options[i].text;` rather than `select.options[i].value;`.

Your resultant JavaScript would thus look like:

```
var select = document.getElementById('prgid');
for (i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    var prg = select.options[i].text;
    if (prg.substring(0, 3) != 'SS ') {
        select.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8rc6LL6k/) to demonstrate - note how all options that do not start with "SS " have been removed.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.